# Magento 1.9.3.7 Set expiration time/date for downloadable products

Tags: downloadable, magento1.9.3

Is there a way to set the time for which a purchased downloadable product is valid?

Let's say, I have a downloadable product on my customer account, and this is valid until some specific date.

Thanks for your collaborations or ideas

Comment: Before asking a new question you should accept the previous answer, i can see from your profile that you are not accepting the answer @Julian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, Magento provides an option to set the number of times the user can download the product. There is no option to set expiry date/time by default.

If you want to set a date/time limit and want to expire the link after that, you need to write a custom module for that.

Steps to achieve what you want are:

- Create setting (under **System > Configuration** section) in the module for expiry (number of days) or **create a custom product attribute** for only downloadable products (you can do it from admin panel).
- **Set a cron in your module which will run daily** and check the expiration date by adding expiration days to purchase date (for each order in which a downloadable product is ordered and the download link is active yet).
  If the current date is bigger than or equal to the expiration date, set the link to be inactive.

I hope my answer is clear enough to understand.

If not, you can check [this extension](https://www.extensionhut.com/downloads-time-limit-on-downloadable-products.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can test this extension link listed below for your issue.

I think it will help you with your issue.

But, You have to do some changes in this extension to make it specific for your **downloadable products only** and as per requirement.

> https://github.com/otecco/magento-product-expiration

Answer (score 0):

We have used one of the extensions for our Magento 2 website but we are not sure if they cover downloadable products or not. We sell food / supplement product with limited shelf life and this product works very well for us. You can check the link below and ask the extension developer if they support this feature

[Product with expiry date](https://www.scommerce-mage.com/magento-2-product-shelf-life.html)

Good luck!